# Definition of \$ \frac{mm}{Ampere}\$ (unit of current sensitivity)?

Tags: current, instrumentation, units, sensitivity

I want to know how \$ \frac{mm}{Ampere}\$ (which is the **unit of current sensitivity** of PMMC instruments) is defined?
i.e, How \$ mm \$ is defined in  terms of \$ degrees\$ ?

For eg.:
 \$ \frac{rad}{Ampere}\$ (another unit of  current sensitivity of PMMC instruments) is defined as number of \$ radians \$ of deflections of PMMC (Permanent Magnet Moving Coil)  instruments for \$1 \, Ampere\$ current input ,
where, \$ \quad  \pi \, rad = 180^{ \circ } \$

I searched it in internet but could not find there, so please anyone help...

Comment: `I searched it in internet but could not find there` ...... what text were you searching for?

Comment: Current sensitivity units

Comment: i took text from your question and found a few hits ..... `unit of current sensitivity of PMMC instruments`  ....... i do not know if the results are useful to you

Comment: Please share its link...

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unit+of+current+sensitivity+of+PMMC+instruments&ia=web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meter scale is some radius r from the pivot so the movement it traces along a circular path would be proportional to the angle.

The circumference of the whole circle path is \$2\pi r\$ for 360° (2\$\pi\$ radians), so you can easily work out the number of mm per angular degree (or radian) of pointer rotation along the scale.